# Statistical test for PCR and bacterial culture with two different testing methods

Tags: biostatistics, mcnemar-test

I have previously used McNemar's test to compare PCR and bacterial culture using the same sample. I now have two different samples from the same patient taken from tonsills and quincy. So I now have 4 results from 4 different tests. Does there exist a statistical test to compare all of my data? Using McNemar's test I can only compare 2 of the tests against each other.

Answer (score 2):

[Cochran's Q test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test) is a generalization of the McNemar test when outcomes are binary, as they seem to be in your case (positive/negative infection assessment by either PCR or bacterial culture).

Whether that's a wise choice in this circumstance is a separate question. That might tell you whether there are any differences but it won't provide much more information. It also would tend to ignore systematic differences between tonsil and [quinsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peritonsillar_abscess), which are of a different nature than a simple difference between test results on the same type of sample.

I suspect that a [mixed logistic regression model](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/) would be more informative. For each combination of sample type and test you would have a separate data row, having 0/1 as the test result along with annotations for sample type, test type, and an ID for the clinical case. Fixed effects would be sample type, test type, and their interaction. A random intercept for ID would account for the within-patient correlations.